# Variation of resistance within conductor due to Skin effect

Tags: skin-effect

What is Skin effect? I learnt that it is a property exhibited by all conducting materials to restrict the flow of current ( eventually ac ) at higher frequencies to their boundary.

My question is does the resistance vary within the conductor i.e. higher at core and decreasing towards boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The skin effect is the effective reduction in the cross sectional area of a conductor that carries high frequency AC. The **current density** is higher on the outside of the conductor than it is an the inside. The actual resistivity of the conductor is still uniform throughout.

Its essentially an example of back emf which is strongest in the middle of the wire produced by the changing magnetic field of the AC.

[image]

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Comment: I understand but how does the eddy current do it?

Comment: @UdhayanMukerjee look at the direction of the red loops - they oppose current towards the centre and "enhance" it towards the outside.

Comment: oh thanks..@JIm Dearden and @Andy aka I understand so the Counter electromotive force generated by eddy Current is responsible for the Skin effect...